# Yarn not deploying due to hardhat compatibility

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm a data engineer intern, and I've taken an interest in understanding smart contracts.

I've tried to create the following project: https://speedrunethereum.com/challenge/simple-nft-example and I've had some trouble with yarn (both chain, start and deploy) apparently due to compatibility with hardhat and tenderly/hardhat-tenderly (No matching version found for @tenderly/hardhat-tenderly@^2.1.1.), as well as ethers (TypeError: ethers.getContract is not a function)

For "yarn chain" there was the error
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
But I changed the node version from v18 to v16 and it worked

then for yarn start, it didn't work at all (didn't run, only output was "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: bad option: --openssl-legacy-provider", when I used the --openssl... and without it, nothing outputed), so I solved it by using nvm start

now for yarn deploy there was the error that " ethers.getContract is not a function"

I was expecting the deploy to work, opening the contract at localhost, but it didn't run.

I suspect some of my previous "solutions" might have affected that, maybe the version incompatibility with hardhat, tenderly and ethers.

The solutions I found involved changing the packages.json, which I included the hardhat in devDependencies and resolutions (from this thread https://github.com/Tenderly/hardhat-tenderly/issues/51

Regarding ethers, I don't understand the reason why it's not showing, as it's on the "deploy_your_contract.js", and I've even created a console.log that shows the get.Contract in the deploy step, before the error comes.

When I tried npm or yarn upgrade ethers (as maybe it was a version problem, and that's kinda how I tried to solve them) this was the result:
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
npm ERR! The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined)

BTW, I use windows 11, on vs code

i'm using node v16.13.0 (only one I was able to go through with chain and start, compared to v18)

In package.json the version for hardhat-tenderly is     "@tenderly/hardhat-tenderly": "^1.0.13",
Ethers is     "ethers": "^5.4.4",
Hardhat is     "hardhat": "2.8.0",
and yarn 4.0.0-rc.46.git.20230623.hash-2259237

This is my first question, thanks for your time, it's greatly appreciated. I tried to put as many detaisl (relevant ones) as I could